# How to assign a function the mousedown event of an NSButton in Cocoa without subclassing?

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa, delphi

I'm trying to find a way to get notified of all NSResponder "events", but without having to subclass the NSControl I'm interested in. For example, I would like to get notified about mouse events from NSButton without having to subclass it. I know there is a way specific for mouse events, but I'm interested in all events provided by NSResponder, including Key events.

Is there a way to do it, like in C# or Delphi where you attach a function to an event?

Edit: I would like to do it at runtime.

Regards

Comment: You can assign Key Equivalents/Keyboard shortcuts through IB(Interface builder) for NSButtons.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question to specify I would like to do it at runtime.